# Match a date to a time date format in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to get records from my database which are added on a specific date, for example records added on the 2013-09-05.  However the records are stored in my database in datetime format so 2013-09-06 08:22:35

I have tried to use a like format thinking it might just match the first half but that makes no difference.

```
  SELECT search_term, COUNT(search_term) as count FROM $tableName WHERE client_id = '{$client_id}'  AND timedate LIKE '$dates' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT $start, $limit
```

I would be grateful for suggestions or a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to get date part from datetime, so change:

```
...AND timedate LIKE '$dates'...
```

to

```
...AND DATE(timedate) = '$dates'...
```

or you could also do:

```
...AND timedate LIKE '$dates%'...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date using `DATE_FORMAT`

Use in Query as below,

```
AND DATE_FORMAT(timedate, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = '$dates'
```

[**Document**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)